# If $P(A \leq C) \leq 1/2$ and $P(B \leq D) \leq 1/2$ then $P(A+B \leq C+D) \leq$?

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables

Let us say, we have two pairs of random variables about which we know the relationship between each pair of the random variable. Is it possible to comment on the relationship of the sum of these pairs?

Intuitively, I would guess that if $P(A \leq C) \leq 1/2$ and $P(B \leq D) \leq 1/2$ then $P(A+B \leq C+D) \leq 1/2$. However, I am unable to prove the same statement.

Edit: $A$, $B$, $C$ & $D$ are independent random variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPD] A counterexample for your statement.

We can take independent random variables $A, B, C, D$ to meet the following. Lets say $\xi=C-A$ and $\eta=D-B$ and additionally $\xi$ is normally distributed with the mean equal to zero, and $P(\eta=2^k)=P(\eta=-2^{-k})=\frac12$ for some natural $k$, so $P(\xi \ge 0) = P(\eta \ge 0) = \frac12$ and
$$P(A + B \le C + D) = P(\xi+\eta \ge 0) = $$
$$=P(\eta=2^{k})P(\xi\ge-2^k) + P(\eta=-2^{-k})P(\xi\ge2^{-k})=$$
$$=\frac12P(\xi\ge-2^k) + \frac12P(\xi\ge2^{-k})$$
The last goes to $\frac34$ when $k\to\infty$

Exact $A, B, C, D$ could be:

- $C \sim N(1, 0.5) \text{ and } A\sim N(1, 0.5)$ so $\xi=C-A\sim N(0, 1)$
- $P(D=2^k)=P(D=-2^{-k}) = 0.5$ and $P(B=0)=1$, so $\eta=D-B=D$

Comment: I wanted to say $A$, $B$, $C$ & $D$ are independent random variables. I don't think this example would hold in that case. (I have edited the problem statement to reflect the same)

Comment: edited to support independence